# MongoDB Get distinct formats from a field

Tags: regex, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a phone number field with different format of phone numbers

```
 +90 224-XXXXXXX
 +90 223-XXXXXXX
 +90 228-XXXXXXX

 (0221) XXX XXXX
 (0224) XXX XXXX
 (0222) XXX XXXX
```

can mongodb help in getting all distinct phone formats ?

Expected output is : 2

Comment: If you don't know all possible formats, I think it's not possible

Comment: What is a format? You have to answer this question first.

Comment: a regex that defines your phone format like : `^\+?\d+(-\d+)*$`

Comment: You cannot distinct on anything except unique values currently without pulling them out yourself in either a Map Reduce or client side.

Comment: I do not know in how many different formats the phone number is saved in my DB
I'm trying to get count of distinct formats the number is stored as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) for this, albeit in a wonderful mapReduce way:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(

    // Mapper - replace all digits with "X"
    function() { 
        emit( "pattern", this.number.replace(new RegExp("[0-9]","g"), "X") ) 
    },

    // Reducer
    function(key, values) {
        var result = { items: [] };

        values.forEach( function(value) {
            // Only add *not found* items to result
            if ( result.items.indexOf( value ) == -1 ) {
                result.items.push( value );
            }
        });

        return result;
    },

    // Output
    {  out: { inline: 1 } }
);
```

That will give something like:

```
{
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "pattern",
                    "value" : {
                            "items" : [
                                    "+XX XXX-XXXXXXX",
                                    "(XXXX) XXX XXXX"
                            ]
                    }
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 4,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 3,
            "emit" : 3,
            "reduce" : 1,
            "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

As I guess this is just for inspection. But you could use the returned `items` part to construct `regex` templates if you wanted to do updates or something else useful I suppose.

Comment: pls correct, it is value, not values in reducer function

Comment: @StephenTalari That's what happens when I just type into a response without copying from code. Oops

Answer (score 0):

Keeping simple, this code worked.

```
db.collection.mapReduce(

// Mapper
function() {     
    emit( this.phone_number.replace(new RegExp("[0-9]","g"), "X"),1 )     
},

// Reducer
function(key, value) {
    return Array.sum(value);
},

// Output
{  
    out: "tmp_collection"
}
);
```